# How to get previous row of dataframe given index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to get the previous element in a dataframe.
My code below shows 30, which is the current one.
How can show 20, the previous one of the current?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20,30]}, index=['2021-11-24','2021-11-25','2021-11-26'])
df1['A']['2021-11-26']  # the current one
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df1['A'].shift()['2021-11-26']
# 20
```

Or [`DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
df1.shift()['A']['2021-11-26']
# 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

- filter the df from beginning to the index value you have
- take last

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 20, 30]},
                  index=['2021-11-24', '2021-11-25', '2021-11-26'])
before_idx = df.loc[df.index < '2021-11-26', 'A'].iloc[-1]
print(before_idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `shift` and `loc`:

```
# fill_value=0 to avoid to get a float number
>>> df1.shift(fill_value=0).loc['2021-11-26', 'A']
20
```